# Как распарсить JSON в iOS

Tags: ios, json, парсер, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый день. Мне нужена помошь с JSON на iOS. Мне надо расшифровать числа в разделе "des" и вложить его в `Label`. Все парсеры слишком большие и сложные, нет никакого простого урока. =( Помгите...

Это весь код страницы которую надо распарсить

```
{"des":1.00,"dem":1085.16,"spo":1.44,"def":0.66,"cap":1.84,"all":11739,"win":53.42,"lvl":6.77,"status":"noerror","name":"_shuzik_"}
```

P.S. Не пинайте меня сильно, я новичок. Честно я пытался разобраться =(

---

Если кому-то нужно пользуйтесь, я нашел самый легкий (Для меня) вариант

добавляем `AFNetworking` и `HTMLParser` в проект, скачать это можно везде.

В .h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *allLabel;
```

Я добавлял по нужде `UILabel`

В .m

```
#import "InfoViewController.h"
#import "HTMLParser.h"
#import "AFJSONRequestOperation.h"

// тут все теги которые нам нужны, можно писать отдельно, можно через заятую в зависимости от того что вам нужно. 

#define iAll  @"all"

@interface InfoViewController ()

@end

@implementation InfoViewController

@synthesize allLabel = _allLabel;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://......."];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"JSON %@", JSON);
        NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *)JSON;

        if (data)
        {
            // так как на выходе получаем нс намбер, его нужно завернуть в нс стринг - иначе краш

            NSString *editAlltext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [data objectForKey:iAll]];
            self.allLabel.text = editAlltext;

        }

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){
        NSLog (@"Err : %@", error);
    }];

    [operation start];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

Я работаю через XIB  так что за тем, пошел в XIB выкинул на монитор Label и соединил его с `allLabel`

Надеюсь, написал понятно. Пользуйтесь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да где же сложные, у [SBJSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework) только и надо что дернуть на пришедшей строке JSONValue, получив на выходе массив или словарь. А в 6 айоси еще и свой появился, я правда его еще ни разу не использовал

Comment: Вот в этом и проблема, очень много файлов, черт пойми что с нимим делать. Можно tutarial по этому ???

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? Вытягиваете исходники, добавляете к проекту, а где хотите использовать - #import "SBJson.h" и вперед

Comment: Спасибо попробую!

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку ни каких меток по поводу языка нет, предлагаю вариант на `Си`:

```
char des[100];
if( sscanf( pJSON, "{\"des\":%[^,],", &des[0] ) == 1 ){
  // в des теперь значение переменной 'des' из буфера pJSON
  SetLabelText( des );
}
```

Если есть возможность задействовать `sscanf_s`, то это будет предпочтительнее. Поскольку нужен только текст, то не предлагаю парсить `des` во `float`, но если нужно - напишу. Хотя, наверное ради верификации значения можно сделать лишнюю работу:

```
char des[100];
float fdes;
if( sscanf( pJSON, "{\"des\":%f,", &fdes ) == 1 ){
  // в fdes теперь значение переменной 'des' из буфера pJSON
  sprintf( des, "%f", fdes );
  SetLabelText( des );
}
```

Comment: Желательно б на языке Obj-с  =)

Comment: @Святослав: а разве obj-c -- не надмножество чистого C?

Comment: @mega: для JSON разрешены пробелы до/после двоеточия. И поле `des` может быть и не первым. И `des` оно может быть подполем какого-нибудь другого поля (например, `spo`): JSON -- рекурсивная штука. Так что от собственноручного написания или использования готового парсера не уйти.

Comment: >для JSON разрешены пробелы до/после двоеточия. И поле des может быть и не первым. И des оно может быть подполем какого-нибудь другого поля

@VladD, здесь дан конкретный `JSON`, с конкретной задачей, на которую я предложил простой ответ. Если бы речь шла о каком-то динамическом запросе, с нескольких серверов, на которых объекты `javascript` заворачивались бы разными генераторами, то я бы понял Вашу озабоченность. Но если схема `JSON` статична, то полноценный парсер не нужен.

Comment: @mega: ну, это какой-то нечестный подход. если считать, что формат входных данных никогда не поменяется, тогда почему вообще не прочитать подстроку по фиксированному смещению от начала строки? ваш код парсит не конкретный JSON, а конкретную строку.

Comment: >ну, это какой-то нечестный подход

Что значит нечестный? Что спросили, то и ответил. Из всех предложенных на данный момент вариантов - самый оптимальный.

>почему вообще не прочитать подстроку по фиксированному смещению от начала строки?

А почему бы и нет? Предложите и такой вариант, он будет самым быстрым. Но в моем случае еще производится проверка, удовлетворяет ли запрос минимальным требованиям условий задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Я сам использую [SBJSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework)
Там есть 2 главных метода

- .- (NSString *)JSONRepresentation; //переобразовать обьект в json строку
- .- (id)JSONValue; //переобразовать json строку в обьект

  ```
  NSString *ourString = @"{\"des\":1.00,\"dem\":1085.16,\"spo\":1.44,\"def\":0.66,\"cap\":1.84,\"all\":11739,\"win\":53.42,\"lvl\":6.77,\"status\":\"noerror\",\"name\":\"_shuzik_\"}";

  NSDictionary *jsonDic = [ourString JSONValue];

  NSString *jsonString = [jsonDic JSONRepresentation];

  NSString *desStriing = [jsonDic valueForKey:@"des"];
  ```

Все очень удобно, Пробуйте.
Мне для удобной работы вполне достаточно

- JSON.h
- NSObject+SBJSON
- NSString+SBJSON
- SBJsonBase
- SBJsonParser
- SBJsonWriter

Comment: Спасибо, попробую !